# How to configure vcpkg for multi project solution

Tags: visual-studio-2019, vcpkg

I am seeking advice on how to proper configure a multi project solution in relation to third party c++ libraries added with vcpkg.

1. How do you checkout a specific version of a library for a project?
2. How do you configure Visual Studio 2019 to use this version for debug and release (lib, dll, headers)?
3. How do I share the configuration with other developers and build servers?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

1. fork vcpkg repo to local repository (TFS Git in my case)
2. make a project-specific branch (project being internal company project, not Visual Studio project)
3. pile on my own port modifications
4. add few scripts that build a package containing only libraries aforementioned project needs (nuget on windows, 7zip for Linux), see `vcpkg export` command
5. label with package version (e.g. 1.0.0.2)
6. build and deploy to a share (that is properly backed up)
7. configure some IIS instance in company network to serve packages from aforementioned share
8. in Visual Studio related projects refer to nuget package
9. on Linux related cmake script pulls correct version of package using http GET, unpacks it and imports vcpkg cmake file
10. every time a change needs to be made to the package:

    - modify your vcpkg branch, label with next version and push
    - build new package version (filename should contain version)
    - deploy package to that share
    - update your cmake files and/or nuget config files

Answer (score -1):

I also tried to export only 1 library (cpprestsdk) but instead vcpkg just exported everything it had installed! Can't it just export the dependent libs only?

```
vcpkg export cpprestsdk:x64-windows --zip
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?